# Pass request.user parameter to modelformset_factory form

Tags: python, django

So I've a formset tied to a model and one of the fields in that is `ForeignKey`.

**models.py**

```
class Squad(models.Model):
    rid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)        
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team.tname
```

**forms.py**

```
class SquadForm(ModelForm):     
    class Meta:
        model = Squad    

    def __init__(self, logged_user, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SquadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['team'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Team.rows.get_my_teams(user=logged_user), empty_label="None")
```

As you can see, the `__init__` function is expecting an extra parameter `logged_user` which I'm hoping to pass via the views.py file. But if I do the following:

**views.py**

```
def choose_teams(request):      
    teamformset = modelformset_factory(Squad, extra=2, form=SquadForm(request.user))

    form = teamformset(queryset=Squad.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'foo.html', {'form':form})
```

I'm trying to pass the logged in user as a parameter on line 2 but this is resulting in the following message:

> Field 'id' expected a number but got 'SquadForm'

Not sure what I'm missing here. But if I remove the parameter from line 2:

```
teamformset = modelformset_factory(Squad, extra=series.team_number, form=SquadForm)
```

it starts working (of course, I no longer expect the user in the forms.py file and remove it too) but shows all the data and not filtered one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass additional keyword arguments to your formset form by passing [form_kwargs={}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms) to your formset

```
class SquadForm(ModelForm):     
    class Meta:
        model = Squad    

    def __init__(self, *args, logged_user, **kwargs):
        super(SquadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['team'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Team.rows.get_my_teams(user=logged_user), empty_label="None")


teamformset = modelformset_factory(Squad, extra=2, form=SquadForm)
form = teamformset(queryset=Squad.objects.none(), form_kwargs={'logged_user': request.user})
```

Comment: That is resulting in `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'logged_user'` error message. I had just did that a few minutes ago taking reference from another SO answer, but doesn't seem to work for `modelformset_factory`

Comment: @asprin changing `SquadForm. __init__ ` so that `logged_user` is a keyword argument should work. Updated the answer

Comment: Yep, saw that. It's working now. Will accept as answer when system allows me to. On another thought, curious about the position of `logged_user` in the `__init__` function. Should it always follow the `*args` argument? What if I need to pass two more more arguments? Does it become `def __init__(self, *args, logged_user, param2, param3, **kwargs)`

Comment: @asprin any argument that follows `*args` or just `*`  with a plain name is a keyword only argument, meaning it must be passed as a keyword. Usually best to define additional arguments to forms this way as data and files are usually passed as positional arguments. So to answer your question, yes that is the way to add more parameters